# How to extend IdentityUser with a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to extend IdentityUser with a foreign key(BuildingID). Below is my ApplicationUser class which derives from the IdentityUser class. What would be the correct way to add the foreign key?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int BuildingID { get; set; }
}
```

I am using a Entity Framework Core

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually foreign keys are used in relational databases not in C# code.  Are you using a database  or a database framework?

Comment: That way you are just adding a normal column. What you have to do is to properly add Navigation Property, then configure the entities throught `Fluent Api` (in the `OnModelCreating`)

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core?

Comment: @atiyar I am using Entity Framework Core

Comment: What is the relation between `Building` and `ApplicationUser`? One-to-Many or One-to-One?

Comment: @atiyar One-to-One

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

This was for a One-To-Many Approach

I changed my ApplicationUser class to the following:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int BuildingID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BuildingID")]
    public Building building { get; set; }
}
```

I then added a migration via the Package Manager Console:

```
add-migration identity-user-extention
```

After the migration was complete I edited the generated code and removed all of the code that created and dropped tables. The reasoning behind this was that it was trying to recreate all of my tables that were already generated.

```
public partial class identity-user-extention: Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "BuildingID",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 0);

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUsers_BuildingID",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            column: "BuildingID");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AspNetUsers_BUILDING_BuildingID",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            column: "BuildingID",
            principalTable: "BUILDING",
            principalColumn: "BUILDING_ID",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AspNetUsers_BUILDING_BuildingID",
            table: "AspNetUsers");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUsers_BuildingID",
            table: "AspNetUsers");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "BuildingID",
            table: "AspNetUsers");
    }
}
```

I saved the migration and then ran the following in the Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Database
```

I was then able to create an account successfully with a buildingID as a foreign key(the Buildings table was already populated)

Comment: I'm not so sure about editing/deleting the migration-generated code. A new migration doesn't create existing table again. If your tables and data are ok, then fine. An important matter is, now you `ApplicationUser` is the dependent entity, so deleting a building will delete all the related users, because EF by default uses Cascading. I'll edit my answer to post a new entity config so that Cascading doesn't happen.

Comment: It was quite strange when I tried to run it normally it said that the table already existed(I can't remember the exact issue or maybe I interpreted it incorrectly which is highly likely) .Thank you for the help once again !

Comment: @atiyar by it deleting all of the related users it ends up being perfect for my use case !

Answer (score 2):

This is an opinionated answer.

When using ASP.NET Core Identity, in my experience, it is better leave the `IdentityUser` alone, for authentication etc purpose. But if your application is not that large/complex, I think this user **can** get into relationship with others entities.

In your case, since `Building` and `ApplicationUser` are in one-to-one relation, I'd suggest not to put the foreign key property in the `ApplicationUser` class. Instead put it in the `Building` class. That way, no new column will be created in the `AspNetUser` table (i.e. it will be left alone), and you will be making `Building` the dependent entity, not the `ApplicationUser`. So if you with to use `Cascading` feature, deleting a `Building` will not delete the related `ApplicationUser` but the other way around.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public Building Building { get; set; }
}

public class Building
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }    
}
```

Configuration is something like -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Building>().ToTable("Building");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Building>(e =>
    {
        e.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        e.Property(p => p.Id).UseIdentityColumn<int>();     
        e.Property(p => p.Address).IsRequired(false).HasColumnType<string>("nvarchar(128)");
        e.Property(p => p.ApplicationUserId).IsRequired(true);
    });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Building>()
        .HasOne(e => e.ApplicationUser)
        .WithOne(p => p.Building)
        .HasForeignKey<Building>(e => e.ApplicationUserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

Comment: I got confused in the moment and for some strange reason thought it was a One-to-One relationship but it was a One-to-Many. I am testing a method that may be a solution. Thank for your help !

Comment: I added my solution above -I would love to hear your comment on it as you are a lot more experienced than me and I would like to know if it was ethical or not.